# Truncating integers in format() in Python 2.7

Tags: python, string, format

Using the "old" formatting syntax I can truncate long integers in a string, like this:

```python
'%-5.5s' % 4257647474747
```

which produces `42576`

If I try to do the same with `format()`:

```python
'{:<5.5}'.format(4257647474747)
```

I get the error `ValueError: Precision not allowed in integer format specifier`

I need to be able to truncate the incoming number, because it must fit in a fixed size string. Is there any way to truncate the integer using format?

Comment: Assign it to a string without truncating, then use a string slice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `s` in `'%-5.5s'` converts arguments to strings with `str` and then applies `%s`'s interpretations for the `-5.5`. You're not doing anything similar in your `format` call, so you're getting the `int` type's interpretation of `<5.5`.

Convert your integer to a string before formatting it:

```
'{:<5.5}'.format(str(4257647474747))
```

or use `!s` in the format string to do the same:

```
'{!s:<5.5}'.format(4257647474747)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this ! operator in the format function